# Why does YQL return additional tags?

Tags: html, json, xpath, yql

I am making a query in the YQL console with the following content:

```
select * from html
where url='http://www.motorni-masla.net/index.php?main_page=product_oil_info&cPath=140&products_id=294&zenid=c8281021bbfed454176247900b3b9d4a'
and xpath='//*[@id="productPrices"]'
```

The idiea is to find out the element with id "productPrices" and return the content of it in JSON.

But when I do it - the result is different than the original code - there are additional tags.

Original content:

```
<strong>
<h2 id="productPrices" class="productGeneral">
<span class="normalprice">14.00лв. </span>&nbsp;<span class="productSpecialPrice">11.00лв.</span><span class="productPriceDiscount">
<br>Спести:&nbsp;21% отстъпка</span>
</h2>
</strong>
```

YQL result:

```
{
   "h2": {
    "class": "productGeneral",
    "id": "productPrices",
    "strong": {
     "span": [
      {
       "class": "normalprice",
       "content": "14.00лв."
      },
      {
       "class": "productSpecialPrice",
       "content": "11.00лв."
      },
      {
       "class": "productPriceDiscount",
       "br": null,
       "content": "\nСпести: 21% отстъпка"
      }
     ],
     "content": "  "
    }
```

Basically in the original content - the order is:
    `strong -> h2 -> span`
And in the YQL result it is:
    `h2 -> strong -> span`

This makes the XPATH i have useless, because i can't use it in the YQL statement - it doesnt fit the result YQL is getting.
In another case not only the order is different, but there is a `<p>` tag added from nowere.

I'd be very grateful if someone tells me what is going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The markup of the page is invalid. Apparently, YQL's parser is doing one thing to fix it, and browsers (or at least, my version of Chrome and apparently whatever browser you're using) are doing a different thing to fix it.

The invalid bit is that you can't put an `h2` inside a `strong`. The content model of [`strong`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-strong-element) is phrasing content, but [`h2`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements) can't go in phrasing content, it can only go in flow content.

Comment: Can I somehow tell the YQL's parser to render it as a browser? Does this mean, that pages with invalid markup cant be scraped?

Comment: I'm sure pages with invalid markup can be scraped, but you'll have to tailor your xpath to YQL's interpretation of the resulting DOM rather than your browser's. Invalid markup is just that: Invalid. That means that whatever parser is reading it can do whatever it thinks is necessary to correct it, and different parsers are going to make different decisions. I doubt there's a YQL flag saying (in effect) "Don't be yourself, be WebKit." :-)

Comment: OK, seems reasonable enough. :)